# Follow redirect with node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I'm trying to learn node.js, and I'm working on a utility to log in on a site, and then exctract some info. I have read that redirects should "work automatically" in the documentation, but I can't get it to work.

```
request({
    url: start_url,
    method: 'POST',
    jar: true,
    form: {
        action: 'login',
        usertype: '2',
        ssusername: '****',
        sspassword: '****',
        button: 'Logga in'
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body, response.statusCode);
        request(response.headers['location'], function(error, response, html) {
            console.log(html);
        });
    }
});
```

First, I do a POST, which gives a respone.statusCode == 302. The body is empty. I expected the body to contain the redirected page.

Then I found the "new" url, in response.headers['location']. When using that, the body just contains a "not logged in" page, instead of the page I was expecting.

Anyone know of how to go about this?

Comment: action = "login" what this mean? What is your filename ?

Comment: That's just some form-data that the server expects.

Comment: Yes. is it correct with extension?

Comment: It's not a file reference. Brandon Smith found the acutal problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Redirects are turned on by default for ***GET*** requests only. To follow the redirects in your ***POST***, add the following to your config:

```
followAllRedirects: true
```

Updated Code:

```
request({
    url: start_url,
    method: 'POST',
    followAllRedirects: true,
    jar: true,
    form: {
        action: 'login',
        usertype: '2',
        ssusername: '****',
        sspassword: '****',
        button: 'Logga in'
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body, response.statusCode);
        request(response.headers['location'], function(error, response, html) {
            console.log(html);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! Worked on first try with followAllRedirects!

Comment: This does not appear to work with `request-promise` -- my `.then()` block doesnt' ever fire.

Comment: just to be super clear - by "config" you mean the options object past to request? is there another config you can change?

Comment: Correct, the object you pass to request. See line 4.