# Node.js Request equivalent of jQuery AJAX .complete()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a Node.js API to register a user to another web app. The problem is, during registration process, the API that the Node app requested with `request` is `301` redirected to another API to complete the registration.

This problem can be solved if I'm using jQuery AJAX and wait for the `.complete()` callback to make sure the redirection is successful.

How can I accomplish this with Node.js `request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is caused by a redirect to a POST (non-GET) HTTP request, which is disabled by `request` at default. I should've enabled this option to follow any kind of HTTP request:

`followAllRedirects: true`

Details in this link: [Follow redirect with node.js request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540232/follow-redirect-with-node-js-request)